# vtp or vtk file loading in Three.js(vtk loader) is not working

Tags: three.js, vtk

I'm trying to load vtp(or vtk) files in Three.js,using vtk loader, but It doesn't work.

I got error message saying "THREE.BufferAttribute: array should be a Typed Array."

So, I searched some informations, and I think that problem is related to parsing vtp file.

(some decoding?problem I guess..?)

I got my vtp file from here [vtp files](https://data.kitware.com/#collection/586fef9f8d777f05f44a5c86/folder/59de9dd58d777f31ac641dc3).
I tried all of it but It didn't work.

my code is same as https://threejs.org/examples/?q=vtk#webgl_loader_vtk

what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems the loader is not able to load the mentioned VTK assets? Any chances to convert the VTKs to a different 3D format?

Comment: @Mugen87 Oh, okay. I'll try converting vtk to another format. Thank you !